# Using PyQgis to count number of features in category

Tags: pyqgis, feature-count

Is there a way I can use pyqgis to count the number of features in different categories in one layer? I am using rule based renderer, and realizing that for some rules the feature count is actually empty zero, so I would like to remove those categories:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use [getFeatures](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a34d5f22eeef1ebb67dc757f6415a481e) to list all records and count with [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
layer = iface.activeLayer()
field = 'KKOD' #Change to match your fieldname
c = Counter([f[field] for f in layer.getFeatures()])

>>c
Counter({3: 6875, 7: 2853, 5: 1642, 6: 1580, 13: 1212, 8: 326, 4: 171, 11: 61, 12: 21, 1: 20, 2: 11})
```

[image]